# three.js Apply image on existing object

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I try to add an img on one object to change his aspect. But all my test result by white object...

The purpose is juste to apply an image on object (all face). He my test code :

```
var obj = scene.getObjectByName('wall_20_118')
var texture = new THREE.ImageLoader().load( 'core/img/3d/shutter.jpg' );
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture,side:THREE.DoubleSide });
obj.material = material
obj.material.map.needsUpdate = true
```

The object turn to white but I can see my image.

How can I do that ?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `THREE.TextureLoader` and it's asynchronous, which means that the image is loaded and a callback function will be invoked once the loading finished and the image can be used as a texture on the object.

You would have to change your code like this:

```
var obj = scene.getObjectByName('wall_20_118');
new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'core/img/3d/shutter.jpg', function onLoad(texture) {
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide 
  });
  obj.material = material
} );
```

Comment: I try your code but now my wall is transparent and I get :
VM355:76 THREE.WebGLShader: Shader couldn't compile.
VM355:92 THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog invalid shaders

Comment: Yup, sorry - I copy & pasted more than I should have - it should be the `TextureLoader` not the `ImageLoader`.

Comment: well then I suggest you reduce your code and see where it breaks. Here is an example that works just fine: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/strong-llama?path=script.js:1:0

Comment: Ok in your exemple it's work but not on my project, object is issue from sweethome3d.
I make another test, if object has already a texture it's work but if not I get white color.

Comment: then you need to show us a better testcase (i.e. more of your code). We can't guess what's wrong in your code unless you show the relevant bits to us.